# http://api.ローカルIPアドレス:3000 にアクセスできない

Tags: network

同じネットワークに入って

- iPhoneのSafariで`http://IPアドレス:3000`にはアクセス**可能**
- `http://api.IPアドレス:3000`だとアクセス**不可能**

となってしまいます。

ちなみにiPhoneアプリから同様にアクセスしてみても

> NSLocalizedDescription=指定されたホスト名のサーバが見つかりませんでした。

というエラーが出てしまいます。

おそらく `api.数字.数字.数字.数字` となっているのでドットが本来のIPアドレスよりも1個多くなってしまっているのがあやしい気がするのですが、解決方法はるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`api.example.com`というホスト名`api`・ドメイン名`example.com`の組み合わせをDNSで名前解決することによって、IPアドレスが得られ通信できる仕組みです。IPアドレスのドットが多いではなく、根本的な理解の問題です。

解決方法として簡単に挙げられるのは以下の二つです。

- `http://IPアドレス:3000`のままアクセスする
- `http://api.example.com:3000`などで名前解決できるようにローカルネットワークを構成する

Answer (score 3):

**セキュリティに関する注意事項: 外部のサービスですので、機密性が高い情報を扱う場合には注意してください。**

ホスト名の仕組みについては @htb さんの解説にある通りですが、手っ取り早く解決する方法として、xip.io や nip.io を利用する方法があります。これらのドメイン名では、

```
IPアドレス.xip.io
任意の文字列.IPアドレス.xip.io
IPアドレス.nip.io
任意の文字列.IPアドレス.nip.io
```

というホスト名がそのIPアドレスにマッピングされています。

たとえば、api.192.168.1.100.xip.io は 192.168.1.100 として名前解決されますので、お望みの動作に近いことができると思います。

なお、ローカルホストに限定すると、lvh.me という同様のサービスがあります。

Comment: なるほど。xip.ioってインストールして使う簡易のDNSかなにかだと思ってましたが、純粋にどこかネットの向こうにあるサービスなんですね。こういうのがあるんですね。