# ローカルDNSを使ってアクセスするとActionController::RoutingError が起こる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, network

[http://api.ローカルIPアドレス:3000 にアクセスできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36838/http-api-%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%ABip%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B93000-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) の続きです。

dnsmasqを入れて、`expand-hosts`を有効にしてアクセスはできるようになりました。

`/etc/hosts`の内容

```
ローカルIPアドレス  api.example.com
```

しかし、`ActionController::RoutingError`が起こります。

RailsのAPIのルートは下記のように設定してあります。

```
namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: {subdomain: 'api'}, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  ..
end
```

正常に値が返ってくるときには、ログに（例えばローカルPCから`api.localhost:3000`としてアクセスした場合）下記が出力されています。

> Processing by コントローラ名#index as JSON
>     Parameters: {"subdomain"=>"api"}

`api.example.com`でアクセスした場合、上記ログが出ていないのでうまくsubdomainの機構がうごいていないようです。

Comment: そもそもですが、iPhoneのネットワーク設定について設定していますか？ネットワーク詳細からDNSサーバのIPを書いてます？プライベートDNSを使うならiPhone側でそのDNSを読みにいくようにネットワーク設定が必要です。

Comment: @Myaku プライベートDNSを使うようにiPhoneのネットワーク設定済みです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Railsで`api.localhost`にアクセスするために

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0
```

を設定していたのが原因でした。
参考： [how to access subdomains locally with Rails 5](https://gist.github.com/indiesquidge/b836647f851179589765)

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 1
```

に修正して

`/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`に下記行を追加

```
address=/api.hoge.com/ローカルIPアドレス
```

して

`$ sudo brew services restart dnsmasq`で再起動でいけました。

補足：

```
address=/api.example.com/ローカルIPアドレス
```

ではそもそもiPhoneからRailsまで辿り着けませんでした。